Is the JSON Data API available for Apache Cassandra 5.x?
I wanted to know if the JSON  Data API  that is the newest DataStax API for writing applications that store and query unstructured document data , Is this available in APache Cassandra 5.X ?
Any suggestion or option to use JSON  Data API using open source Apache Cassandra V5.x release .
Appreciate your inputs !
I saw that JSON DATA API its available today in DSE 6.9 , but would like to use the open source version and see if i can test its features.

The Data API for Apache Cassandra works with Cassandra backends which have the latest Storage-Attached Indexing (SAI) features that are currently only available in DataStax Enterprise (DSE) 6.9 and DataStax Hyper-Converged Database (HCD).
The [soon-to-be-released] Apache Cassandra 5.0 will ship with just a subset of the SAI features (commonly referred to as "version 1" or "phase one" features) with the remaining features planned (not guaranteed) for inclusion in a subsequent Cassandra release, provisionally tagged as 5.1 (see Cassandra Enhancement Proposal CEP-7 for details). Again, this is not final since we cannot make promises or guarantees for something which has not been released yet.
The Data API may work on release candidates of C* 5.0 but it is not tested by the developers so its operation will be unpredictable.
I will reach out to the developers of the Data API for confirmation and will update my answer as appropriate. Cheers!

Thanks Erick , Will wait for your updates  from the developers of Data API !

The developers confirmed that the Data API is unlikely to work out-of-the-box with C* 5.0. Some queries might be OK with the incomplete SAI implementation but you're welcome to test based on your use case. One of ours will reach out to you directly to discuss. Cheers!
